# Apache ActiveMQ Artemis unsubscribes from current session when it disconnects a previous session

Tags: activemq-artemis

Apache ActiveMQ Artemis unsubscribes from current session when it disconnects a previous session

Sometimes when we have a network glitch, clients will disconnect and reconnect. What I think we're seeing from time to time is Artemis cleaning up old sessions, and when it disconnects the old session, it unsubscribes the subscriptions of the new session.

These are the logs we captured using a log plugin

```
2022-05-24 08:32:50,448 INFO UserA Connect Broker, Success. Mqtt ClientId=clientA SessionId=18c42139-db3c-11ec-8290-00505683049d SourceIP=/192.168.2.8:40302 
2022-05-24 08:32:50,448 INFO UserA Connect Broker, Success. Mqtt ClientId=clientA SessionId=18ef01cf-db3c-11ec-8290-00505683049d SourceIP=/192.168.2.8:40302 
2022-05-24 08:32:51,198 INFO UserA Unsubscribe Broker, Success. Mqtt ClientId=clientA SessionId=04fb8e9e-d51f-11ec-8290-00505683049d SourceIP=/192.168.2.8:37032 Topic=Sample.Test.Topic.A.# 
2022-05-24 08:32:51,198 INFO UserA Unsubscribe Broker, Success. Mqtt ClientId=clientA SessionId=04fb8e9e-d51f-11ec-8290-00505683049d SourceIP=/192.168.2.8:37032 Topic=Sample.Test.Topic.B.# 
2022-05-24 08:32:51,729 INFO UserA Subscribe Broker, Success. Mqtt ClientId=clientA SessionId=18c42139-db3c-11ec-8290-00505683049d SourceIP=/192.168.2.8:40302 Topic=Sample.Test.Topic.A.# 
2022-05-24 08:32:51,901 INFO UserA Subscribe Broker, Success. Mqtt ClientId=clientA SessionId=18c42139-db3c-11ec-8290-00505683049d SourceIP=/192.168.2.8:40302 Topic=Sample.Test.Topic.B.# 
2022-05-24 08:33:03,495 INFO UserA DisconnectedFrom Broker, Success. Mqtt ClientId=clientA SessionId=04fb8e9e-d51f-11ec-8290-00505683049d SourceIP=/192.168.2.8:37032 
2022-05-24 08:33:03,495 INFO UserA DisconnectedFrom Broker, Success. Mqtt ClientId=clientA SessionId=05135c7e-d51f-11ec-8290-00505683049d SourceIP=/192.168.2.8:37032 
2022-05-24 08:33:03,495 INFO UserA Unsubscribe Broker, Success. Mqtt ClientId=clientA SessionId=18c42139-db3c-11ec-8290-00505683049d SourceIP=/192.168.2.8:40302 Topic=Sample.Test.Topic.A.# 
2022-05-24 08:33:03,495 INFO UserA Unsubscribe Broker, Success. Mqtt ClientId=clientA SessionId=18c42139-db3c-11ec-8290-00505683049d SourceIP=/192.168.2.8:40302 Topic=Sample.Test.Topic.B.#
```

We're currently on Artemis 2.16.

Comment: Can you reproduce this on the [latest release](https://activemq.apache.org/components/artemis/download/) (2.22.0 at this point)? There's been a lot of changes to the MQTT implementation since 2.16.0 including support for MQTT 5.

Comment: We haven't tried on the latest and it's not readily reproducible.

Comment: I strongly recommend you upgrade ASAP. If the issue still occurs on the latest version then [report the issue](https://activemq.apache.org/issues) officially. Generally speaking, community (i.e. free) support concentrates on the latest version to ensure the issue in question hasn't already been fixed.

Comment: Have you had a chance to test on the latest version?